# Clarification of a fact in Isaacs's Finite Group Theory

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I was revisiting group theory in detail and reading Isaacs's Finite Group Theory book in my own time. I need a little clarification on one claim made in the proof of Theorem 2.18. This is on page 62 of the book.

Here is what we should start with:

> $G$ is a finite group, $A$ and $B$ are abelian subgroups of $G$. Consider the set $\{ A\cap B^g \mid g \in G\}$ and $M$ is a minimal member of this set in the sense that no member of the set is properly contained in $M$.

In the very first line in proof of Theorem 2.18, it is claimed that

> The set $\{ A\cap B^g \mid g \in G\}$ is unchanged if we replace $B$ by an arbitrary $G$-conjugate $B^g$, and thus it is no loss to assume that $M = A \cap B$.

I can understand the fact that the ser is unchanged if we replace $B$ by an arbitrary $G$-conjugate $B^g$ but my question is

> Why we can assume that a minimal member $M =A\cap B$?

Possibly it is very trivial and apologies in advance but any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Because conjugation is transitive on the conjugates of $B$

Comment: Please replace the images of text in your question by actual text to make it accessible for users with screen readers etc.

Comment: You just replace $B$ by $B^g$ if necessary to ensure that it is minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M$ be a minimal member of $\{A\cap B^g \mid g\in G\}$, then $M=A\cap B^{g_0}$ for some $g_0\in G$. Let $B'=B^{g_0}$ so that $M = A\cap B'$ while
$$
\{A\cap B^g \mid g\in G\} = \{A\cap B'^g \mid g\in G\}
$$
since conjugation is transitive on the set of all $B^g$.

Hence, replacing $B$ by $B'$ we may assume that $M=A\cap B$ to begin with.